# Data Table formatting

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a data table with following data

```
Col1  Col2 
----  ----
abc   R1,R2
cde   R3
fgh   R2,R3
```

I would like to convert it into following structure

```
Col1   Col2
----   ----
abc   R1
abc   R2
cde   R3
fgh   R2
fgh   R3
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same?

Comment: Would you like to do this in database or in C#? This is not clear since you specified both tags.

Comment: @STO Its in a datatable which i create using C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var q = dt.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => row.Field<string>(1).Split(',').Select(col2 => new object[] {row[0],  col2}));
var newDt = new DataTable();

foreach (var item in q)
{
    newDt.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: can i know what col2 means in second select?

Comment: this is a parameter of lambda function, receive part of second column (splited by comma).

Comment: I am getting object reference not set to an instance error when i try.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 4 columns in my table and this is what i put in <code>  var q = newRoless.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => row.Field<string>(3).Split(',').Select(col2 => new object[] { row[0], col2 })); <code>

Comment: 4 columns, and the splied column is the last?

Comment: exactly. all are strings

Comment: `var q = newRoless.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => row.Field<string>(3).Split(',').Select(col2 => new object[] { row[0], row[1], row[2], col2 }));`. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for prompt response. I am still getting the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is this due to diff column names i have in my table? My table column names are different and this particular column is named as 'Support Roles'. I have also accepted the answer as it gotten me very close :)

Comment: newRoless = ds_ex.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(false, "TaskID", "TaskName", "MethodTaskID", "Secondary Role");  //getting data here successfully                                                        var q = newRoless.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => row.Field<string>(3).Split(',').Select(col2 => new object[] { row[0], row[1], row[2], col2 }));//getting error in this line.                              var newDt = new DataTable();

foreach (var item in q)
{
    newDt.Rows.Add(item);
}                                 Btw how do i go to new line?? Every time i hit enter i end up posting comment.

Comment: your problem is empty cell (at last column). What you want in this case? one row or anything?

Comment: if its empty i can do with the same row.just now checked. it is the case.

Comment: try: `            var q = newRoless.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row =>
            {
                var splitCol = row.Field<string>(3);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(splitCol))
                    return Enumerable.Repeat(new object[] { row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3] }, 1);
                else
                    return splitCol.Split(',').Select(col2 => new object[] { row[0], row[1], row[2], col2 });
            });`

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the rows and recreate a new DataTable.

The main question is: where does the DataTable come from? If it is from the database, why not change the SQL statement?